# How to undo my JSOG.parse() in order to return to an API

Tags: angularjs, json

**Setting**

I have a spring MVC

I have an angular frontend that (on the press of a button) gets the definition from the backend, changes its name to "NewName" and then attempts to PUT it back with the new name.

**Current Code**

```
  $scope.simpleSaveDefinition = function() {
    Definition.simpleGet({uuid:$scope.definition.uuid}, function (result) {
      result.name = "NewName";
      var stringResult = JSOG.stringify(result);
      Definition.update({'uuid':$scope.definition.uuid}, stringResult);
    });
  }
```

It is calling:
definition.service.js

```
        'simpleGet': {
            method: 'GET', isArray: false, 
            headers: {
                "Authorization": "ABC"
            }, url: "api/v1/definition/:uuid/deep",
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                return JSOG.parse(data);
            }
        },
```

definition.service.js

```
        'update': {method: 'PUT', headers: {"Authorization": "ABC"},
            transformResponse: function (data) {
                return JSOG.parse(data);
            }
        },
```

**Error**

```
Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":{"timestamp":1529075556923,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"JSON parse error: Unresolved forward references for: ; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.UnresolvedForwardReference: Unresolved forward references for: \n at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 5685]Object id [2] (for com.ibm.ispww.serviceregistry.domain.swagger.media.Schema) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 3257], Object id [17] (for


    ...

(for com.myregistry.domain.assemblies.NamedObject) at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 5676].",
  "path" : "/api/v1/definition/fac4e40b-8b41-4eca-94d2-6054ee2a0bd7"
}
```

So, the error seems to be that

```
JSOG.parse(result) 
result.name = "NewNAME"
JSOG.stringify(result)
```

Does not result in an acceptable object.

Interestingly, if I remove these steps, and just get the object (never parse) and return it, it works.

**Question**

Is there some way of parsing a result, editing it, then unparsing it and returning it? It seems that JSOG just doesn't work in the way I expected it to.

Comment: Typo: `JSON.parse`; not `JSOG`. There is no need to manually parse JSON; the $http service does that automatically.

Comment: https://github.com/jsog/jsog I think I was using this, but using JSON worked. Thanks @georgeawg